# Using Paired-t test for n > 30 non-normal difference

Tags: statistical-significance, normality-assumption, paired-data

I have data from a paired experiment (each participant does both the control and experiment and we find the difference). I know that for the paired t-test, an assumption is that the difference is normally distributed. I also now that due to CLT, samples of n > 30 can be assumed normal, and that my sample size is 58; however, I ran a Shapiro-Wilk Test for normality and it rejected the null hypothesis that the data is normally distributed. Is it safe to still use the paired t-test? Or should I use another test that does not assume normality, such as the Wilcoxon?

Comment: I naively forgot about the other assumption, which is that the data must not have any outliers. I remove the outliers and ended up with a normal distribution (according to Shapiro-Wilk) with n = 50 (8 outlier removed). Does this seem to be the mistake in my original assessment of the problem?

Comment: Removing extreme observations may remove the most interesting and scientifically meaningful ones.

Comment: The CLT doesn't say anything about whether the difference is distributed normally, it says that sample mean of the differences will tend towards a normal distribution! The fact that your data doesn't pass a Shapiro-Wilk Test doesn't contradict this, since it's testing something else, namely whether the differences themselves are normally distributed. Of course appealing to the CLT is always a bit fuzzy, but as you mentioned the rule of thumb of n > 30 can be applied here. I think you're OK to use a paired t-test as is, without removing outliers.

Comment: @Max One ought to be concerned about the effects of outliers on a t-test.  Without more information about their sizes or quantity, your recommendation appears to have no justification.

Comment: @whuber Good point, I retract the last sentence of my comment. Is it fair to say "The data not passing a Shaprio-Wilk Test does not necessarily imply that a paired t-test is inappropriate"?

Comment: @whuber for context, I tried to use the t-test both with and without removing outliers. p-value with outlier: 0.402657, p-value without outliers: 0.1205999638955149. Although both are not significant at alpha=0.05, the vastly different p-values concerns me

Comment: @Max Yes, that's a very good way to conclude your comment.  Ryohei: those p-values might not be as different as they seem.  In any case, unless you can adopt some strong specific distributional assumptions about the pair differences, the t-test will be among the most powerful options, so the relatively high p-values indicate you're unlikely to detect a significant difference using some other generic test such as the Wilcoxon.

Comment: @whuber So is the conclusion that based on the information I provided, the paired t-test without removing outliers is a strong enough test to conclude statistical significance?

Comment: And is it preferred over using the Wilcoxon test

Comment: Neither of those should be inferred.  Your p-values are so large, you cannot conclude there is a significant difference.  Perhaps the Wilcoxon test would be better in this case, but it will not produce a result with a significant p-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there are $n$ paired differences $D_i.$ It seems worthwhile
to emphasize that the paired t test assumes that $\bar D$ is nearly normal.
The rule that $n \ge 30$ is sufficient for $\bar D$ to be normal is too
simple. For some distributions of the $D_i,$ a dozen observations would
suffice, and for others, thirty observations are not enough. A reasonable
clue whether thirty are not enough would be that the sample is obviously
heavily skewed or for the sample to contain far outliers.

For example, suppose $n=40.$ If $D_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 0.3, \sigma=1),$ then
$E(D_i) = 0.3$ and $SD(X_i) = 1.$ However, if $D_i \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1) - 0.7,$ then we also have $E(D_i) = 0.3$ and $SD(X_i) = 1,$ but the distribution of $\bar D$ is
noticeably non-normal, as illustrated below.

```
set.seed(2020)
a.exp = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(40)-.7))
summary(a.exp)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.2568  0.1895  0.2915  0.2998  0.4009  1.2210 
hist(a.exp, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="Skewed Dist'n of Means")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(a.exp), sd(a.exp)), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Below are boxplots for twenty samples of size $n=40$ of such "exponential"
paired differences $D_i.$ Clearly, these samples typically show fair warning of skewness, often along with high outliers.

```
set.seed(1234);  m = 20;  n = 40
d = rexp(m*n) - .7;  g = rep(1:m, n)
boxplot(d ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
abline(h=.3, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The departure of the distribution of sample averages from normal is enough to degrade
the power of the t test to detect population paired difference of $0.3$---
from about 46% to about 44%,
as illustrated in the simulations below:

```
set.seed(611)
pv.exp = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(40)-.7)$p.val)
mean(pv.exp <= .05)
[1] 0.43727

pv.nor = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(40,.3,1))$p.val)
mean(pv.nor <= .05)
[1] 0.45735
```

However, in case the distribution of the $D_i$ is clearly not symmetrical, a one-sample
Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test is ***not an attractive alternative*** to the paired t test: This Wilcoxon
test would have only about 16% power to detect a difference of $0.3.$

```
wpv.exp = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rexp(40)-.7)$p.val)
mean(wpv.exp <= .05)
[1] 0.16366
```

Overall, the Wilcoxon test is not quite as powerful as the t test for normal data (which are symmetrical), but
the loss in power from about 46% for a t test (above) to about 44% for
the Wilcoxon SR test is not so great for normal data.

```
 wpv.nor = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rnorm(40,.3,1))$p.val)
 mean(wpv.nor <= .05)
 [1] 0.44338
```

It is true that nonparametric tests work in some circumstances where
data are not normal. However, nonparametric tests can have their own essential assumptions,
and for the Wilcoxon SR test, symmetry of the data is an important assumption.